# 403 not working after changing DirectoryIndex

Tags: php, .htaccess

I disabled directory browsing in my .htaccess file, and recently I have changed my default index page, which works. But now when I browse to: *domain.com/images/* it's suppose to give me a 403 forbidden error, but it just goes to the index page '*/en/index.php*' itself.

```
#Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on

#Disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

#Default index page
DirectoryIndex /en/index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

#Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]

#Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stylesheets/$
RewriteRule ^/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]

#English
RewriteRule ^what-is-minecraft/$ /en/what-is-minecraft.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^getting-started/$ /en/getting-started.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^mods/$ /en/mods.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^best-mods/$ /en/best-mods.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms-of-service/$ terms-of-service.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$ privacy-policy.php [NC,L]

#French
RewriteRule ^fr/cest-quoi-minecraft/$ /fr/cest-quoi-minecraft.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/demarrage/$ /fr/demarrage.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/mods/$ /fr/mods.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/meilleurs-mods/$ /fr/meilleurs-mods.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/$ /fr/index.php [NC,L]
```

Can anybody figure out what's the problem?

**EDIT**: Posted my complete .htaccess code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you would not need to remove the trailing slash as it is not being appended to the redirect of php files and you don't need to worry about existent files or folders as they won't be rewritten either.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove the php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

# Does not end with trailing slash redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# To internally redirect /anything to /anything.php if /anything.php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/en/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ en/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm, and does exactly what I want it to do with less code. One question though, I don't see where you have specified the DirectoryIndex in your code?

Also, there should be added a trailing slash to all the URLs so that I dont have any duplicate urls. /anything should go to /anything/ too if anything.php exists.

Comment: @KidDiamond `/anything should go to /anything/ too if anything.php exists` yes it will because I have the trailing slash on the rule `^(.+?)/?$` as optional. Your hosting server probably have `index.php` already by default so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: Ah, I see. But upon proper inspection I found your code is actually not working properly. My content files are stored in domain.com/en/ and domain.com/fr/. With your code, when I visit any of my pages it gives me a 404 error. Only thing that's working is my domain.com root.

Comment: Should work for any folders unless you have other rules that are conflicting with the above rules.

Comment: Yes. Instead of a snippit of my .htaccess code I have edited it and posted my whole .htaccess code. Can you check if there are any conflicts?

Comment: `terms-of-service.php` and `privacy-policy.php` are on the root folder right? rest is on the en or fr folders right? and what does not work is `http://domain.com/what-is-minecraft/` with my code correct?

Comment: See update including the needed rules you had previously, keep in mind `terms-of-service.php` and `privacy-policy.php` should be on the root folder and the `en` / `fr` files on their respective folders.Oh and you should use a different browse to test of change 301 to 302 while testing to avoid it from caching your browser until you confirm its fully working.

Comment: I think it works now. Only let's say a link like this 'domain.com/fr/cest-quoi-minecraft' is not redirecting to the appended / like 'domain.com/fr/cest-quoi-minecraft/'.

Comment: I think this is it. Thank's a lot for your help. :)